# What happens to controls created in a method after the method is done?

Tags: c#, winforms

for example in this code:

```
void ButtonCreator()
{
    Button elboton = new Button();
}
```

what happens with `elboton` after I call this method?

Comment: Why would anyone do this?  To get a button to show up on the screen you would need to add it to the Controls collection of some container...and at that point other things will be referencing it and it will not be GC'd.

Comment: @Bryan Batchelder: I am doing stuff with webpages on webBrowser's that are hidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're not referenced by some other object (e.g. a container), then they become unreachable and are eligible for collection by the garbage collector.  This is the same as creating any other object.

Note that the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class (and its subclasses like `Button`) all implement the `IDisposable` interface, so the easiest way to make sure any *unmanaged* resources associated with the `Button` are released is to use a `using` block, like so:

```
using(Button elboton = new Button()) {
    // Do whatever you need to do
}
// elboton is now disposed
```

However, any *managed* resources associated with the object won't be reclaimed until the GC runs, regardless of whether or not you use a `using` block.

Comment: @D.P.: is the garbage collecting done automatically? or how do "summon" it? =P

Comment: Yeah, the GC runs sporadically when the runtime "feels" it makes sense to do so.

Comment: so, can GC be called programmatically? or just "when the runtime feels it makes sense to do so"?

Comment: It *can* be called programmatically, but that's usually not a good idea - let the runtime handle this, it knows more about the computer and the memory situation than your application. (To trigger a collection, have a look at the `GC` static class.)

Answer (score 0):

All references to it are destroyed and in turn the garbage collector will eventually gobble it up.  If you assign that button to exist in some other context (add a reference to it that last beyond the scope of this method) it will stay.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no reference on that instance and it will be cleaned up by the GC after a while...

Answer (score 0):

In your example `elboton` will be collected by the GC (garbage collector) when the next GC iteration starts. This is because it is not referenced just after ButtonCreator() finishes.